# Passing Data From JavaScript To MVC is possible?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind two dropdownlist. How can I call ddlObject.value from JavaScript to x.stateID at place with ******? Please help me.

Sorry my English :)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>State</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("StateID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Iller, "İl Seçiniz", new { @class = "form-control", @onChange = "chooseCity(this)" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <select id="City"></select>
    </div>



<script>
    function citySecim(ddlObject) {

        document.getElementById("State").innerHTML = '@{
        Context db = new Context();
        List<City> cities = db.City.Where(x => x.stateID == ****I WANT TO WRITE ddlObject.value HERE****).ToList();
        foreach (var city in cities)
        {<option value="@city.cityID">@city.cityName</option>}
        }';
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are mixing server side and client side up, this is going to give you all sorts of issues. Create a web handler that accepts your selected state and returns a list of cities in that state. Then on the client in JavaScript populate the cities drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mix server-side and client-side code in view page, because server-side code immediately renders when the page is loading and you need another way to pass client-side variable value into server-based LINQ query.

Since you want to perform cascading dropdownlist, use `change` event on first dropdown to trigger AJAX callback targeting a controller action instead, as given in example below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>State</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("StateID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Iller, "İl Seçiniz", new { @class = "form-control", id = "state" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>City</label>
    <select id="City"></select>
</div>
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$(function() {
    $('#state').on('change', function () {
        var stateId = $(this).val();

        // use jQuery.ajax() or simplified jQuery.getJSON() to pass first dropdown value into action method
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCity", "ControllerName")', { stateID: stateId }, function(result) {
            if (!result) 
                 return;
            $('#City').append($('<option></option>').text('Select City').val(''));
            $.each(result, function(index, item) {
                 $('#City').append($('<option></option>').text(item.cityName).val(item.cityID));
            });         
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller Example**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCity(int stateID) 
{
    using (Context db = new Context())
    {
        List<City> cities = db.City.Where(x => x.stateID == stateID).ToList();

        // returns JSON data object from list of cities
        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

A similar `DropDownList` approach can be found in Stephen's example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym).

Comment: I could'nt do your example but I did through Stephen's example. So thanks a lot :)